# How to view mgo's bson.Raw in "pretty" text

Tags: go, bson, mgo

I want to be able to output raw bson data I am getting from golang's mgo library to the console for debugging purposes, but have been unable to find out how to accomplish this.

With JSON I do it like this:

```
    formatedData, err := json.MarshalIndent(rawData, "", "   ")
        if err != nil {
        log.Print(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("%s", formatedData)
```

Is there an equivalent way to do this with BSON?

Comment: Are you using this https://godoc.org/labix.org/v2/mgo/bson ?

Comment: Yes, I am using godoc.org/labix.org/v2/mgo/bson

Answer (score 2, accepted):

bson is a binary format and it is just a slice of bytes. It is in itself not readable by a human as this format holds information about the length of fields, etc. and holds all data very compact. It is already encoded, so there is no need to marshal it.

You can output as it is, but it will be not readable.

See the bson spec here: http://bsonspec.org/#/specification

If you want to see all contents of the bson, you could Unmarshal it into a map:

```
m := map[string]interface{}{}
rawData.Unmarshal(&m)
fmt.Printf("%+v\n", m)
```

Comment: Thanks mbuechmann, that did the trick. It also made me realize I overthought it too much, as I could also just put it into an interface then run it through my prettyJSON function. I appreciate the assistance.

Comment: Slight variation to make it work for me: 
`err := bson.Unmarshal(rawData, &m)`